# Trouble with golang compiler/setting go path

Tags: go, path

I have attempted setting a go path to multiple directories using export, i.e

```
export GOPATH=$(mktemp -d)
```

or

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go"
```

etc.

I have attempted using multiple directories yet when I attempt to run `"go get"` I always run into the same error.

> /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/github.com/golang/protobuf/proto/text.go:39:2: no Go source files in /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/encoding

All signs seem to point to the gopath not being set but I can assure you I have set it multiple times attempting to troubleshoot and when I cd to `$GOPATH` it brings me to the gopath I set.

If it is of any concern this is the repository I am attempting to access:

https://github.com/layeh/piepan

Thank you

Comment: looks like the problem is GOROOT, not GOPATH. what's the output of `go env`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  GOPATH was set, but not present in "go env".  Turns out that I had an older installation of go in /usr/bin/go that superceeded the installation in /usr/local/go/bin/go in my path.

Changing the PATH to ensure that /usr/local/go/bin/go came first solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

The GOPATH environment variable specifies the location of your workspace. It is likely the only environment variable you'll need to set when developing Go code.

To get started, create a workspace directory and set GOPATH accordingly. Your workspace can be located wherever you like, but we'll use $HOME/go in this document. Note that this must not be the same path as your Go installation.

> $ mkdir $HOME/go
>
> $ export GOPATH=$HOME/go

For convenience, add the workspace's bin subdirectory to your PATH:

> $ export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin

you have to add you $GOPATH to $PATH, execute highlighted commands (change to your path)